# Is it possible to make a background service app in iOS which is invisible to user and hidden from springboard?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, hidden, springboard, service-application

I want to make a background service app in `iOS` just like we have Intent-filter in android(without an activity) which in invisible to user but still exits on the device.

I need to keep a database file in this service app which user only need to instal in the device, but is not launchable or visible to user.

I've tried using SBAppTags in `info.plist` and it successfully hides the app icon from springboard but only for simulator and not for real iPhone device. As of iOS 8, Apple has closed off the SBAppTags feature so that one cannot use that to hide apps from springboard. Is there anything else that can be used in iOS similar to this?

In android, I've created Intent-filter for the service app which only needs to be installed once from the play store and thereafter remains invisible to user.

If anyone has done something similar in iOS, please comment below.

Comment: iOS does not provide support for this..

Comment: Any trick or hack? @DroidGEEK

Comment: iOS has limited background modes. There are some hacks, top of my mind is, you can keep a socket connected to a server when your app is in the foreground but if your app is in the background you should use either silent push notifications or PushKit notifications if your app is a VoIP app. 
Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't get it. My requirement is to just hide my app from user i.e. prevent it from launching and remove it from springboard. @DroidGEEK

Comment: You can't hide your app from the user in iOS. Also, it is unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve. Lastly, don't use code formatting for emphasis!

Answer (score 1):

Background service is a feature provided by `Android`.

In `iOS`, the best you can do is create a task, eg. a download task and handover it to the `OS`, when the app enters in background.

But, this background task will only run for max 30 sec or so(you can never predict). And can be killed by the OS anytime, without any notification.

```
    let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

    if let downloadURL = URL(string: "YOUR FILE URL"){
        let downloadTask = session.dataTask(with: downloadURL)
        downloadTask.resume()
    }
```

Also if you want to use background service for specific tasks like VOIP, you need to add it to your **Capabilities**

[image: Configure background modes]

[Download task documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background)

[Background Modes documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)